Bug in retrieving data from replit db
there Problem retrieving data from replit db
The code was able to call data. The code was able to call data until yesterday but suddenly the problem occurred where it does not show any errors But the bot remains stuck at the point where it calls data from db
keys = db.keys()
print(list(keys))
I tried different ways to print the data but nothing prints and sometimes it prints I tried different ways to print the data but nothing prints and sometimes only part of the data is printed  The code keeps getting stuck trying to load data.
keys = db.keys()
print(list(keys))
Or
def load_subscriptions():
print("Loading subscriptions...")  # طباعة لإظهار بدء عملية التحميل

subscriptions = {}

for key in db.keys():

    print(f"Checking key: {key}")  # 

    if key not in ['one_month_codes', 'three_month_codes', 'used_codes', 'welcome_caption', 'used_trials']:

        expiry_date_str = str(db[key])

        try:

            subscriptions[int(key)] = {'expiry_date': datetime.strptime(expiry_date_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}

            print(f"Loaded subscription for key {key} with expiry date {expiry_date_str}")  # 

        except ValueError:

            print(f"Error parsing date for key {key}: {expiry_date_str}")  

print("Finished loading subscriptions.")   

return subscriptions

user_subscriptions = load_subscriptions()
print(f"User subscriptions loaded: {user_subscriptions}")
The data is supposed to be printed, but the bot stops trying to fetch the data without any benefit or errors appearing.
